# Remove "Add To Compare" link from below product image in category page

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

1. I followed this tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527218) to remove Add to Compare, it worked. But is their a better way of doing it, like editing local.xml file instead.
2. How can I remove "View Details" just below it in category page.
3. By following the steps in point number 1, "Add to Compare" seems to be gone but there remains a lot of empty space.[image] How should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Find the style class and display: none

Comment: I did not understand it.